# Issue with Ray not distributing tasks fairly. Heavily biased towards the Master node

Tags: python, python-3.x, distributed-computing, ray

I'm trying to distribute a function over an EMR cluster using Ray. The number of tasks(5,000) are much more than the number of available CPUs(512). My issue is that Ray is not distributing tasks to all the nodes fairly(PFA the Server Load Distribution from Ganglia). I do see from command line prints that its actually launching tasks in other nodes(also visible by the light green color in some nodes in the distribution below), but its way more focused on the master node(The red node in the distribution below). This is not very helpful as I'm getting better speeds using the `multiprocessing` library's parallelization in one large 96 core instance.

Any advice on what might be going wrong and how to make Ray fairly distribute tasks over all nodes and cores would be very helpful. Thanks!

[image: Server Load Distribution]

Comment: Hmmm I'd expect better scaling than this from Ray. How large are your tasks (i.e. approximately how long do they take to execute)?

Comment: the tasks vary could vary between fraction of a second to a few seconds. I'll try distribute the task load such that an atomic task takes more time, and have less number of tasks overall. Maybe that'll help in keeping the master busy and distribute the load.

Comment: I'm a ray developer, currently working on scheduling, and it seems like this shouldn't happen. Would you mind filing a bug on github (ideally including a reproduction if possible). https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/new?assignees=&labels=bug%2C+triage&template=bug_report.md&title=

Comment: Sure, let me replicate the issue with an open source dataset and file the bug by the wknd. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Ray always try to schedule locally first in order to optimize the performance (and that’s why your master node has the highest load because your driver is running there normally). There are many ways to load balance workload across the cluster. For example, you can specify resources (like num_cpus, so that ray will schedule tasks on other nodes when there are not enough resources on the head node by other tasks) or use an API called placement group; https://docs.ray.io/en/master/placement-group.html

I also recommend you to post this on Github discussion so that you can get more techniques from other users :)! https://github.com/ray-project/ray/discussions

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Sang! I tried placement groups, it actually helped a bit but nodes other than the master are still poorly utilized. For my use case, I'm trying to parallelize a lot of fairly small tasks (ml models), that should not take more  than 1 core, so I guess specifying n_cpus wouldn't be the best way?

Comment: After doing some more digging I found the dynamic custom resource allocation section (https://docs.ray.io/en/master/advanced.html#dynamic-custom-resources) that seems like it should help in load balancing. Going to try it next, maybe implement a round-robin strategy for node utilization. There aren't any examples doing this though:(. Please update the answer if you are aware of any.. In the mean time I've added the question in ray discussions page, hopefully will work up a solution soon. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @kabrapankaj32 I just saw your reply actually. Have you figured this out? If so, I'd love to add an example to our documentation !